# Creating many YouTube iframe players slows down initial page load

Tags: jquery, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I'm using the youtube api to add alot of videos, more than in this example, 15 for one page and 30 for another; the logic is identical

```
// load  api
  var tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.src = "//www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  // make player array
  var players = new Array();

  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    players[0] = new YT.Player('player1', { //player1 is a div id in the html, this is how it works throughout the page
      height: '405',
      width: '720',
      videoId: 'Sqd3jUPq3Lw',
      playerVars: { 
          'rel': 0, 
          'enablejsapi': 1,
          'iv_load_policy': 3
          }
    });
    players[1] = new YT.Player('player2', {
      height: '315',
      width: '560',
      videoId: 'Sqd3jUPq3Lw',
      suggestedQuality: 'large',
      iv_load_policy: '3',
      playerVars: { 
          'rel': 0, 
          'enablejsapi': 1,
          'iv_load_policy': 3
          }
    });
    players[2] = new YT.Player('player3', {
      height: '315',
      width: '560',
      videoId: 'Sqd3jUPq3Lw',
      suggestedQuality: 'large',
      iv_load_policy: '3',
      playerVars: { 
          'rel': 0, 
          'enablejsapi': 1,
          'iv_load_policy': 3
          }     
    });
     players[3] = new YT.Player('player4', {
      height: '315',
      width: '560',
      videoId: 'Sqd3jUPq3Lw',
      iv_load_policy: '3',
      playerVars: { 
          'rel': 0, 
          'enablejsapi': 1,
          'iv_load_policy': 3
          }
    });
      players[4] = new YT.Player('player5', {
      height: '315',
      width: '560',
      videoId: 'Sqd3jUPq3Lw',
      playerVars: { 
          'rel': 0, 
          'enablejsapi': 1,
          'iv_load_policy': 3 
          }
    });
    players[5] = new YT.Player('player6', {
      height: '315',
      width: '560',
      videoId: 'Sqd3jUPq3Lw',
      playerVars: { 
          'rel': 0, 
          'enablejsapi': 1,
          'iv_load_policy': 3 
          }
    });
    players[6] = new YT.Player('player7', {
      height: '315',
      width: '560',
      videoId: 'Sqd3jUPq3Lw',
      playerVars: { 
          'rel': 0, 
          'enablejsapi': 1,
          'iv_load_policy': 3 
          }
    });




  }
//to stop the video from playing
  $(document).click( function() {
    //loop players array to stop them all
    $(players).each(function(i){
       this.pauseVideo();
      });
  });
```

The trouble with the above code is that the iframes take a long time to load on the page.  This interferes with other javascript, such as triggering the modal windows that contain some of the videos.

In the next example, I broke the videos into 3 arrays, 2 of which are triggered on events such as modal button events.

```
// load  api
  var tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.src = "//www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  // make player array
  var players = new Array();
  var players2 = new Array();
  var players3 = new Array();

  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    players[0] = new YT.Player('player1', {
      height: '405',
      width: '720',
      videoId: 'Sqd3jUPq3Lw',
      playerVars: { 
          'rel': 0, 
          'enablejsapi': 1,
          'iv_load_policy': 3
          }
    });




   $('.btn-1').click( function(){

      players2[0] = new YT.Player('player3', {
      height: '315',
      width: '560',
      videoId: 'Sqd3jUPq3Lw',
      suggestedQuality: 'large',
      iv_load_policy: '3',
      playerVars: { 
          'rel': 0, 
          'enablejsapi': 1,
          'iv_load_policy': 3
          }     
    });
     players2[1] = new YT.Player('player4', {
      height: '315',
      width: '560',
      videoId: 'Sqd3jUPq3Lw',
      iv_load_policy: '3',
      playerVars: { 
          'rel': 0, 
          'enablejsapi': 1,
          'iv_load_policy': 3
          }
    });
      players2[2] = new YT.Player('player5', {
      height: '315',
      width: '560',
      videoId: 'Sqd3jUPq3Lw',
      playerVars: { 
          'rel': 0, 
          'enablejsapi': 1,
          'iv_load_policy': 3 
          }
    });



  });


   $('.btn-2').click( function(){


  players3[0] = new YT.Player('player7', {
      height: '315',
      width: '560',
      videoId: 'Sqd3jUPq3Lw',
      playerVars: { 
          'rel': 0, 
          'enablejsapi': 1,
          'iv_load_policy': 3 
          }
    });
    players3[1] = new YT.Player('player8', {
      height: '315',
      width: '560',
      videoId: 'Sqd3jUPq3Lw',
      playerVars: { 
          'rel': 0, 
          'enablejsapi': 1,
          'iv_load_policy': 3 
          }
    });
     players3[2] = new YT.Player('player9', {
      height: '315',
      width: '560',
      videoId: 'Sqd3jUPq3Lw',
      playerVars: { 
          'rel': 0, 
          'enablejsapi': 1,
          'iv_load_policy': 3 
          }
    });
   });
   }

  $(document).click( function() {
    //loop players array to stop them all

    $(players).each(function(i){
       this.pauseVideo();
      });   
      $(players2).each(function(i){
       this.pauseVideo();
      });
      $(players3).each(function(i){
       this.pauseVideo();
      });
        });
```

This  does in fact stagger the load time.  The page loads pretty quickly, and while the modals take a bit longer, i feel as if the user would be willing to wait a few additional seconds for the iframes to load.

What doesn't work is that last function to pause all of the videos on document click(useful for when users click out of the modal).  Ironically, if I get rid of the button click events, function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady is able to create iframes for all three arrays.  As soon as those click events are added to the function, the pausevideo function fails.

I've read through the youtube documentation and have not found a solution to this.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your specific question about why all the videos aren't paused when you take the approach of storing the `YT.Player` objects in separate array, I'm going to assuming it's because you're only iterating over the `players` array and calling `pauseVideo()` on each player, and not doing the same for the `players2` (and `players3`) arrays.

To address your larger issue of JavaScript execution delays while loading a large number of players at once, you need to remember that JavaScript execution on a page is single-threaded, and if you're spending time in the `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady()` then that necessarily prevents any handlers or other code from executing in the meantime. So if this is an issue for you, you should try to minimize the time you spend tying up the execution thread in that function. One technique for doing that is to queue up some operations whose execution is [deferred via setTimeout() calls](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/06/28/understanding-javascript-timers/).

This could look something like (untested):

```
var players = [];

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    players.push(new YT.Player('player1', {
      // Your player1 config here...
    }));
  }, 0);

  // Many other window.setTimeout() calls...

  window.setTimeout(function() {
    players.push(new YT.Player('player50', {
      // Your player50 config here...
    }));
  }, 0);
}
```

You might also see some benefit from adding `controls: 2` to your `playerVars`, as [documented here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#controls).

As an aside, you're specifying `iv_load_policy` as a value in the options passed in to the `YT.Player` constructor. That doesn't accomplish anything; you should put it in as a value in the `playerVars` section (which you're already doing).

Comment: Jeff, thank you for your work on this.  The solution that I used was to build out the player variables in the url of iframes, then I used jquery to change src to data-src to enable and disable the iframes on specific click events.  While, probably not the youtube suggested method, it works fine and was much less of a headache than the pile of javascript I started with.  Again, thank you, that was truly helpful, and definitely improved my understanding of event handlers.